# ElasticsearchRepository- findAllByPostId returning unexpected results. Possible issue with the ID

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have the models **Post** and **Comment**, whose ID are annotated with @Id.

When saving a Comment, I save both his ID and the PostId

```
@Document(indexName = "comments")
@Data
public class Comment {

@Id
private String commentId;

private String postId;
```

My problem is that when searching for all the comments with PostId "**-z6OOHMBrExEkdIZ_aCH**", this is returning all the comments in database...

It looks that there is an issue with the initial hyphon/dash.

Do you know how to avoid it? Is it possible to define the @Id not to include this (and maybe other) special characters.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

Spring Data method:

```
List<Comment> findAllByPostIdOrderByCreationDateAsc(String postId, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: What is the spring data jpa method are you using for this?

Comment: List<Comment> findAllByPostIdOrderByCreationDateAsc(String postId, Pageable pageable);
@Santoshb

Comment: which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: The latest one:

   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: can you update your Pageable class?

Comment: It is not for sure problem of the Pageable. It is not about not returning values, but about returning results whose IDs does not correspond with the one provided =/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using this query

```
List<Comment> findByPostIdOrderByCreationDateAsc(String postId, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: I tried and I get the same results. I changed the ID manually deleting the initial "-" and now everything is working fine.

Comment: I need to find a way for my Elasticsearch models to change the format of the @Id, for example, using an UUID2, but I still did not find anything